# Scanned film show bright border around the edge

Tags: film, developing

My scan result (using the Epson 600, the film is Fuji Pro H 400, not expired) showed the top and bottom of the film strip significantly brighter than the middle:

[image: example 1]

And here is a more extreme example:

[image: example 2]

I suspect it's because of the developing tank I'm using:

[image: developing tank]

This tank leaks like a waterfall when doing an inversion, but it has a string stick and the reel moves up and down thanks to a pattern at the bottom.

So I followed the advice of some people online. While developing this roll of Fuji 400H, I kept stirring and did not invert the tank.

The result, as you have seen, is far from ideal. But I am not sure exactly which part caused this, the lack of inversion or the stirring over-agitated the edge of the film, or is it because of something else?